# How to import libraries in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working on a Java program, where it will print the stored string in backwards. And I would like to use the **ArrayUtils** method. 
So, in order to do that, I have to import *org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;* (commons-lang-2.6.jar), which I dont have. And I would like to download it and add it to the library. 
Once I am in the *commons.apache.org* page and look for commons-lang-2.6.jar, there are actually 2 sections : 
Binaries, and Source.
 Which one should I download and how do I add the library?

Comment: You just need the binaries. Source if you want the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"how do I add the library?"*

To add a new Library to NetBeans,

- do the following (*after* downloading and extracting the library you need)

  1. If you click `Tools -> Library` a popup will come up.
  2. There you can add a new library. Click on `New Library` and give a name the new Library.
  3. Import a library from the `ClassPath` tab - click `Add Jar/Folder`, locate and select.
  4. If you want to can also add the javadoc from the `JavaDoc` tab. You would add the file from the library file you downloaded, called `javadoc`. This will allow for the javadocs to be seen while editing your code.
  5. Also you can add the sources file form the `Sources` tab. Import the file named `sources`
  6. Then right-click on the `Libraries` folder icon in your project and `Add Library`
- Another option is just add the `.jar`.

  1. Right-click on the `Libraries` folder icon in your project and click `Add Jar`
  2. Locate the `.jar` file and add it.

Answer (score 0):

the next link contains a jar file which you can import to your project (into libraries):
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/apache-commons/apache-commons-lang.jar.zip

basically, the binaries files are compiled code and that is what you want.